# How can I refresh Shiny app using invalidateLater?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to restart my R app so that it will reload the global.R file on a timer, but can't get it to work. Are there any suggestions?

```
shinyServer(
function(input, output, session) {
  reactive(({
  invalidateLater(60000, session)
  session$reload()
  }))
}
)
```

Comment: Why dont u read in the global.R periodically?

Comment: source(global.R) doesn't work either. I need the ui.R to also refresh (legacy code).

Comment: session$reload() wont load the global.R, you need to restart the app. stopApp()